# How to create a simple search with NDK and C++ files

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I´m a noob in JNI and NDK code, and I have to create a method to use a static library with many methods and headers created in C++.I have to call them from Java . I'll try to explain my problem that I want to resolve this since many days.

I'll try to explain this with some code.

I have this method search in cpp:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <HDTManager.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace hdt;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
// Load HDT file
    HDT *hdt = HDTManager::mapHDT("/storage/emulated/0/Download/linkedmdb.hdt");

// Enumerate all triples matching a pattern ("" means any)

IteratorTripleString *it = hdt->search("","","Batman");
    while(it->hasNext()){
            TripleString *triple = it->next();
            cout << "Result: " << triple->getSubject() << ", " << triple>getPredicate() << ", " << triple->getObject() << endl;
    }
    delete it;
    delete hdt;
}
```

And I have a static library with extension ".a" that contains all the headers and code on which search.cpp depends.

In conclusion, my questions is if you can help me to create a Java class that uses this method from a native call, so i can read a lot of pages and i can`t do that. I think that i have to create this method in a cpp file in a jni folder into the Android project and create a Android.mk which uses the static library "libhdt.a", this create a shared library ".so" that can be used by the Android code using the loadLibrary method.

Another problem is how to load the library that contains the data what i have to search, is located in the storage of the movile phone, i´m talking about this code line:

```
HDT *hdt = HDTManager::mapHDT("/storage/emulated/0/Download/linkedmdb.hdt");
```

Comment: The NDK comes with several example projects. Start by looking at those if you're unsure about how to integrate native code into your app.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your comment. I've tried a lot of examples and did a lot of tutorials but no one shows me how to do something like that, i need this so much because it resolves to me a very important part of a project.

Comment: First, you won't be able to use a prebuilt library that wasn't built with the NDK toolchain.  Once you get past that, the NDK examples show you how to write JNI-compatible code and corresponding Java code - use that knowledge to write JNI glue code which then calls your existing native code.  Do watch out however, for the fact that an Android application process typically outlasts the life of a given Activity or Service instance - you may need to put real thought into what happens when this code is invoked again in the same process.